What is the significance of the photos of an elderly man and woman in the Japanese man's shrine?
In the 2016 South Korean movie The Wailing, there's a scene where both the Shaman and the Japanese man are performing their rituals to ward off an evil spirit. The movie cuts back and forth between the Shaman's scenes and the Japanese man's scenes. During this sequence, we see inside the Japanese man's shrine in his house, and the camera zooms in on old black-and-white photos of an elderly (Japanese?) man and a woman. These photos are separate from another area of the house where various photos of the infected were displayed.

Given the ambiguous nature of the Japanese man's background and motivations, do these photos hold any significance? Why are the photos of the elderly man and woman placed there? Who are the people in these photos?

I hesitate to answer because I can't even tell for sure if this is a Buddist or Shinto family shrine.  However from limited knowledge and some googling, some Buddist sects do place family photographs on home Butsudan (shrines). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butsudan and https://www.hawaiipublicradio.org/general-assignment/2015-12-31/why-traditional-japanese-altars-are-vanishing-with-the-times. So if no-one else answers, my guess would be formal photos of relatives.

@iandotkelly The Catholic priest in the film says the Japanese man is rumored to be a Buddhist monk, but the film also suggests he might not be human. If that’s the case, I’m curious how that would affect the significance of the photos on the shrine.
